Visual Studio uses different user secrets files for "Manage User Secrets" vs. when debugging
The problem
I discovered this problem when one of our development databases went offline, and I needed to point to a different database.
I opened my user secrets in the usual way...

... modified the connection string, hit F5, ... still broken.
After digging around a bit, I found that there are two folders containing secrets.json:
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\one_name-guid1
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\another_name-guid1
By opening and modifying the files via Windows Explorer instead of Visual Studio, I was able to establish that "Manage User Secrets" opens the first one, and F5 uses the second.
Things I've tried
No amount of cleaning seems to fix this. I tried deleting the .vs folder, git clean -x -d -f, and cloning the repository to a different folder.
When I tried renaming the folder that gets used for debugging, it found nothing in secrets.
Workaround
It's going to be awkward if "Manage User Secrets" shows one thing, and F5 uses something else, so I've moved everything out of secrets, into appsettings.development.json.  I don't like it, though, because what if I have to git clean -x -d -f?
Question
How do I get Visual Studio to use the secrets file from "Manage User Secrets" for debugging?
